# Using dispatch_async is useful in willDisplayCell

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in

        //call some method in cell to pass data and update labels/images on cell
    }
}
```

I believe willDisplayCell is always called on main thread. So what am i achieving by using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. I'm new to swift. Please help me understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you need

Comment: Thanks for paying attention. I dont need anything. Trying to understand few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind dispatching from the main queue back to the main queue is to say "I don't want to do something now, but here's something I want to do in the next iteration of the run loop." In this case, this method is called right before the cell is displayed, so it looks like the author is trying to update a cell that is not yet visible, so they want to defer the block until the cell is actually shown.

It depends a little upon what is going on inside that block, but this has a bit of code smell to it. We tend to use this kludgy trick when there is no more direct and intuitive way of achieving the desired effect. In this case, I'd question whether the code in that dispatch block might better belong in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.

Also, the use of `unowned` vs `weak` is also a little worrisome (what if you flicked your finger and there was a scroll in progress and the user dismissed the scene while the animation was still underway). It might be OK, but there might be a sort of race condition here.